# Django: Update distinct queryset updates all records

Tags: python, django, distinct, django-queryset

For a reason I don't understand, When i create a distincted queryset and update it, Django updates all the items in the queryset as if it wasn't distinct in the first place

for example:

```
items = Item.object.filter(SOME-FILTERS).order_by('gender').distinct('gender')
items.update(quantity=F('quantity') - 1)
```

the result is 2 rows update

If I iterate over items it updates only 1:

```
for item in items:
    item.quantity -= 1
    item.save()
```

Comment: I am not sure at all this `distinct` does anything sensible here, for either update or select. However, most probably it is not applied to the update statements (how would the syntax work anyhow in an `UPDATE` statement), and thus your update runs without distinct in it. Disclaimer: IANADP.

Comment: Can you show your data?

Comment: I get only 1 object when checking items, but update statement updates 2

Comment: I checked and Django actually generates this:
UPDATE "item" SET "quantity" = ("item"."quantity" - 1) WHERE "item"."gender" = "F"
For some reason it drops the DISTINCT

Comment: What would you expect to happen? Which row should be updated? `distinct` simply doesn't make sense in an update, and PostgreSQL (which you seem to be using) [doesn't support it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-update.html#Synopsis).

Comment: Where is this code being used? do you even need a quantity field or should it just be a query itself?

Comment: @knbk I would expect the first row in the ordering to be updated. This is what [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) does in a queryset with Postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

The way i found around this problem is to do the below.

```
queryset = Product.objects.values('manufacturerCode').distinct()
queryset = queryset.filter(FreeStock__gt = 0)
```